# To customize a predefined symbol with different colors

Tags: symbols, color

For example I have this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\begin{document}
   \color{red}{\textdbend} 
\end{document}
```

that produces this output:

[image]

By default it is black, but if I add the red color of course the default symbol becomes all monochrome. Is it possible to color parts of a symbol at will (e.g. I would like the black curve symbol) or is it impossible to realize since the symbol is this with one only color?

Comment: the synatx is wrong, it should be `{\color{red}\textdbend}`

Comment: recreate the symbol as an image and you can choose whatever colour you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use colored cow fonts with pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342703/how-use-colored-cow-fonts-with-pdflatex)

Comment: Just saying "This is not a duplicate question." doesn't really help, and may make others more inclined to mark it a duplicate.  You should explain why you think this is not a duplicate.  What is different about this question that the other question and answer isn't sufficient?  And why not TikZ, which works just fine with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Teepeemm 1) Many users seem to close questions without careful and careful reading. The link is not related to my question at all. In summary Off-topic. 2) When my question was marked as duplicate, I added this comment to point out to other users that they should read the question well. 3) Personally, it should also be considered that not everything should be solved with TikZ. 90% of the questions are all with TikZ and I think that many very good users have gone away also because constantly this tag is used as the "panacea" of everything or the medicine that cures all diseases.

Comment: @Sebastiano Arbitrarily editing your question to invalid existing answers is not nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreate the symbol in tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=red,nonzero rule] (6.3749,6.9704) .. controls (4.7212,7.2843) and (4.5592,7.3197) .. (4.3843,7.4055) .. controls (4.0676,7.5611) and (3.8515,7.8680) .. (3.7877,8.2528) .. controls (3.7023,8.7678) and (3.9833,9.3370) .. (4.4429,9.5803) .. controls (4.5299,9.6263) and (5.4053,9.9636) .. (6.3882,10.3299) .. controls (8.2627,11.0284) and (8.3312,11.0594) .. (8.2662,11.1809) .. controls (8.2507,11.2099) and (8.2238,11.2387) .. (8.2065,11.2449) .. controls (8.1893,11.2510) and (7.4079,11.3988) .. (6.4699,11.5732) .. controls (5.5320,11.7478) and (4.7547,11.9006) .. (4.7426,11.9126) .. controls (4.7244,11.9307) and (4.8785,12.8367) .. (4.9182,12.9450) .. controls (4.9249,12.9632) and (4.9515,12.9780) .. (4.9772,12.9780) .. controls (5.0702,12.9780) and (8.5321,12.3141) .. (8.6427,12.2751) .. controls (8.9308,12.1733) and (9.1463,11.9749) .. (9.2820,11.6856) .. controls (9.3543,11.5319) and (9.3666,11.4736) .. (9.3754,11.2408) .. controls (9.3866,10.9470) and (9.3502,10.7714) .. (9.2289,10.5317) .. controls (9.1453,10.3668) and (8.9056,10.1277) .. (8.7312,10.0350) .. controls (8.6584,9.9965) and (7.7790,9.6583) .. (6.7770,9.2838) .. controls (4.8617,8.5679) and (4.8352,8.5559) .. (4.9029,8.4292) .. controls (4.9182,8.4007) and (4.9578,8.3713) .. (4.9909,8.3637) .. controls (5.0240,8.3561) and (5.8060,8.2094) .. (6.7286,8.0377) .. controls (7.9718,7.8063) and (8.4098,7.7154) .. (8.4209,7.6863) .. controls (8.4398,7.6371) and (8.2709,6.7019) .. (8.2349,6.6571) .. controls (8.2203,6.6389) and (8.2010,6.6252) .. (8.1918,6.6264) .. controls (8.1827,6.6278) and (7.3651,6.7825) .. (6.3749,6.9704) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (2.9788,1.1320) .. controls (2.9070,1.1823) and (2.8982,1.3310) .. (2.9636,1.3854) .. controls (2.9992,1.4150) and (3.2874,1.4242) .. (4.4926,1.4349) -- (5.9778,1.4482) -- (5.9851,2.9175) .. controls (5.9891,3.7257) and (5.9866,4.4109) .. (5.9796,4.4401) .. controls (5.9726,4.4695) and (5.9275,4.5157) .. (5.8796,4.5431) .. controls (5.7310,4.6278) and (1.4490,8.9183) .. (1.3190,9.1127) .. controls (1.0264,9.5502) and (1.0150,9.9999) .. (1.2846,10.4611) .. controls (1.3465,10.5670) and (1.9340,11.1744) .. (3.3697,12.6168) .. controls (5.1044,14.3593) and (5.5519,14.7965) .. (5.9182,15.1076) -- (5.9910,15.1694) -- (5.9910,15.6051) .. controls (5.9910,15.9937) and (5.9963,16.0457) .. (6.0394,16.0849) .. controls (6.0809,16.1224) and (6.1599,16.1286) .. (6.5913,16.1286) .. controls (7.0455,16.1286) and (7.0991,16.1239) .. (7.1386,16.0802) .. controls (7.1757,16.0392) and (7.1824,15.9641) .. (7.1824,15.5912) -- (7.1824,15.1506) -- (7.3214,15.0464) .. controls (7.3978,14.9890) and (8.4386,13.9611) .. (9.6341,12.7621) .. controls (11.2725,11.1191) and (11.8311,10.5430) .. (11.9020,10.4232) .. controls (12.0409,10.1887) and (12.0898,9.9930) .. (12.0738,9.7362) .. controls (12.0568,9.4660) and (11.9642,9.2540) .. (11.7434,8.9803) .. controls (11.5323,8.7186) and (7.4364,4.6376) .. (7.3081,4.5609) .. controls (7.2534,4.5284) and (7.2025,4.4758) .. (7.1949,4.4443) .. controls (7.1872,4.4128) and (7.1843,3.7257) .. (7.1883,2.9175) -- (7.1956,1.4482) -- (8.6809,1.4349) .. controls (10.3095,1.4205) and (10.2535,1.4267) .. (10.2535,1.2612) .. controls (10.2535,1.0782) and (10.5239,1.0908) .. (6.5867,1.0908) .. controls (3.4173,1.0908) and (3.0313,1.0952) .. (2.9788,1.1320) -- cycle(6.8515,2.8778) -- (6.8515,4.3075) -- (6.3220,4.3075) -- (6.3151,2.9043) .. controls (6.3113,2.1327) and (6.3141,1.4858) .. (6.3213,1.4671) .. controls (6.3309,1.4418) and (6.4008,1.4349) .. (6.5929,1.4406) -- (6.8515,1.4482) -- cycle(6.9668,4.7456) .. controls (7.1285,4.8237) and (7.3157,5.0033) .. (9.2954,6.9783) .. controls (10.8544,8.5335) and (11.4834,9.1782) .. (11.5756,9.3153) .. controls (11.7885,9.6313) and (11.8081,9.8461) .. (11.6544,10.1735) .. controls (11.5807,10.3301) and (11.3956,10.5226) .. (9.3584,12.5623) .. controls (7.2835,14.6399) and (7.1307,14.7869) .. (6.9549,14.8743) .. controls (6.7973,14.9526) and (6.7385,14.9678) .. (6.5888,14.9686) .. controls (6.4353,14.9696) and (6.3819,14.9558) .. (6.2074,14.8706) .. controls (6.0109,14.7748) and (5.9370,14.7044) .. (3.9562,12.7297) .. controls (2.8296,11.6067) and (1.8343,10.6027) .. (1.7443,10.4983) .. controls (1.5092,10.2260) and (1.4258,10.0473) .. (1.4248,9.8137) .. controls (1.4242,9.6558) and (1.4375,9.6001) .. (1.5136,9.4431) .. controls (1.5976,9.2698) and (1.7363,9.1248) .. (3.7640,7.0930) .. controls (4.9524,5.9020) and (5.9869,4.8848) .. (6.0629,4.8323) .. controls (6.3745,4.6169) and (6.6468,4.5907) .. (6.9668,4.7456) -- cycle(6.8592,15.5181) .. controls (6.8641,15.6564) and (6.8556,15.7502) .. (6.8361,15.7738) .. controls (6.7963,15.8216) and (6.3874,15.8262) .. (6.3404,15.7792) .. controls (6.3111,15.7496) and (6.2927,15.3327) .. (6.3197,15.3056) .. controls (6.3258,15.2996) and (6.4478,15.2957) .. (6.5911,15.2971) -- (6.8515,15.2996) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you generate that TikZ output?

Comment: @siracusa see https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz

Answer (score 3):

`\clipbox` the black symbol and superimpose over the red.  In works for 10-12pt documents as well as in the smaller text sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manfnt,stackengine,trimclip}
\newcommand\textdbendrb{\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lb]{-12}{\rule{0.70ex}{0ex}%
  \clipbox{1.17ex 1.98ex 1.35ex 1.18ex}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lb]{12}{\textdbend}}}}%
  \stackengine{2.03ex}{\textcolor{red}{\textdbend}}{\copy0}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\textdbend \textdbendrb
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

For those, like the astute Sebastiano, who note that, at various magnifications, a red shadow can appear at the edge of the black double-bend, one can take the extra
step of first blotting out the red double-bend with a `\rule`, and *then* overlaying the black double-bend:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manfnt,stackengine,trimclip}
\newcommand\textdbendrb{\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lb]{-12}{\rule{0.70ex}{0ex}%
  \clipbox{1.17ex 1.98ex 1.35ex 1.18ex}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lb]{12}{\textdbend}}}}%
  \stackengine{2.03ex}{%
    \stackengine{1.5ex}{\color{red}\textdbend}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
      \color{white}\rule{2.1ex}{2.1ex}}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
  }{\copy0}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\textdbend \textdbendrb

\tiny\textdbend \textdbendrb
\end{document}
```

As I noted to the OP, if you change in this MWE the `\color{white}` declaration to, for example, `\color{yellow}`, you can visually see the area that I first blot out of the red sign, before overlaying the black double-bend.

Answer (score 1):

Include the symbol as image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
X \includegraphics[height=2ex]{bend} X
\end{document}
```

[image]